# Stop storyboard at exact keyFrame

Tags: wpf, storyboard, keyframe

I made a die for some game I'm making (in c#), it's a usercontrol which uses a storyboard to show several images after each other (like a slideshow) so it looks like a rolling 3D die. The problem is starting and stopping it at a specific keyFrame. It's seems logical to use Pause() and Resume() for this, but I can't figure out how to Pause at an exact keyFrame.

Some people use a seperate dispatcherTimer to do this, but this isn't precise enough to stop it at that exact keyframe. (for example, if you throw 4 it must stop on the 4 image).

So, it would be great if there was some method like this:

```
TimeSpan keyTime = new TimeSpan(0,0,0,0,750); // 750 miliseconds
myStoryBoard.ResumeTo(keyTime); // <- doesn't exist as far as I know
```

Here is a snippet from my storyboard in XAML:

```
<Storyboard x:Key="DieStoryBoard" RepeatBehavior="Forever">

        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.Visibility)" Storyboard.TargetName="image1">

            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0">
                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                    <Visibility>Visible</Visibility>
                </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
            </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame>

            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.05">
                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                    <Visibility>Collapsed</Visibility>
                </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
            </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame>

        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>


        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.Visibility)" Storyboard.TargetName="image2">

            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.05">
                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                    <Visibility>Visible</Visibility>
                </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
            </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame>

            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.10">
                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                    <Visibility>Collapsed</Visibility>
                </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
            </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame>

        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>


        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.Visibility)" Storyboard.TargetName="image3">

            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.10">
                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                    <Visibility>Visible</Visibility>
                </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
            </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame>

            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.15">
                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                    <Visibility>Collapsed</Visibility>
                </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
            </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame>

        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
.....
```

And some images to make things clearer:

[image: 1][image: 2][image: 3][image: 4]

Comment: Maybe it will be easier to compose animation for each case?

Comment: @MaratKhasanov That may actually be doable, there are 36 cases, but since you can change the startingpoint using Seek(), I would need 6. tx! Although I would still like to know if there's a proper way ofcourse.

Comment: Have you figured out how to do it eventually ?

Comment: @MichaelIV No, I have not, I used MaratKhasanov's advice and made 6 seperate animations. Not what I wanted but it did the job.

Answer (score 2):

try this...

my example is a rotating arrow,and I can stop it at a specified angle.

```
<Window.Resources>
    <Storyboard x:Key="Storyboard1">
        <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames     
            Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.RenderTransform).
            (TransformGroup.Children)[2].(RotateTransform.Angle)" 
            Storyboard.TargetName="RightPanelButton1">
            <DiscreteDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0" Value="0.0"/>
            <DiscreteDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:1" Value="45.0"/>
            <DiscreteDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:2" Value="90.0"/>
            <DiscreteDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:3" Value="135.0"/>
            <DiscreteDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:4" Value="180.0"/>
        </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
    </Storyboard>
</Window.Resources>



Storyboard st = ((Storyboard)this.Resources["Storyboard1"]);

st.Begin();
st.Seek(new TimeSpan(0,0,2));
st.Pause();

Abbas Ahmed
```