# C# WPF Stop Storyboard

Tags: c#, wpf, animation, storyboard

im on programming a slot machine. For spinning the wheel i have follwing animation that looks like:

```
        <Border Height="300" Margin="68,434,1506,335">
                <Border.Triggers>
                    <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="Loaded">
                        <BeginStoryboard >
                            <Storyboard Name="stb">
                                <RectAnimation Storyboard.TargetProperty="Background.(ImageBrush.Viewport)"
                                To="0,0,1,1" RepeatBehavior="Forever" />
                            </Storyboard>
                        </BeginStoryboard>
                    </EventTrigger>

                </Border.Triggers>
        <Border.Background>
            <VisualBrush TileMode="Tile" Viewport="0,1,1,1">
                <VisualBrush.Visual>
                    <StackPanel>
                        <Image Source="test.jpg"></Image>
                        <Image Source="test.jpg"></Image>
                        <Image Source="test.jpg"></Image>
                    </StackPanel>
                </VisualBrush.Visual>
            </VisualBrush>
        </Border.Background>
    </Border>
    <Button Name="cmdStop"/>
```

How can i start/stop from Code behind? Thanks for your help.

**EDIT**

I want to it to start / stop with a button not when a page is loaded. how can i solve this ?
The problem is the button should be outside of the border... How can i access the button?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried to pause the anmation?

A good example is found [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/graphics-multimedia/how-to-use-event-triggers-to-control-a-storyboard-after-it-starts) and when you want to pause it from the Code-Behind, use `DataTrigger`instead of `EventTrigger`.

And maybe you are interested in the "Triple the speed of the Storyboard" too.

---

**Edit**
Your Question "I want to it to start / stop with a button not when a page is loaded. how can i solve this ?" cant be answered because when the Page (Border?) is not loaded, the animation cant be running. I Suggest to hide the Page/Border and only make it visible when the animation is paused.

I fiddled a bit around and tried to solve it with the Visibility

```
    <!-- This Border is animated. -->
    <Border Height="300" Margin="68,434,1506,335" >
        <Border.Style>
            <Style TargetType="{x:Type Border}">
                <!-- Here is your animation -->
                <Style.Triggers>
                    <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="Border.Loaded">
                        <BeginStoryboard Name="RandomStoryboard">
                            <Storyboard >
                                <RectAnimation Storyboard.TargetProperty="Background.(ImageBrush.Viewport)"
                            To="0,0,1,1" RepeatBehavior="Forever" />
                            </Storyboard>
                        </BeginStoryboard>
                        <!-- Stop the animation at the Start -->
                        <PauseStoryboard BeginStoryboardName="RandomStoryboard" />
                    </EventTrigger>
                    <!-- Control the animation according to the Togglebutton State -->
                    <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=IsChecked, ElementName=SpinControl}" Value="True">
                        <DataTrigger.EnterActions>
                            <ResumeStoryboard BeginStoryboardName="RandomStoryboard" />
                        </DataTrigger.EnterActions>
                        <DataTrigger.ExitActions>
                            <PauseStoryboard BeginStoryboardName="RandomStoryboard" />
                        </DataTrigger.ExitActions>
                        <!-- Hide the Border while the animation is running -->
                        <Setter Property="Border.Visibility" Value="Hidden"/>
                    </DataTrigger>
                </Style.Triggers>
            </Style>
        </Border.Style>
    </Border>

    <!-- This Button Controls the Animated Border -->
    <ToggleButton Name="SpinControl">
            <ToggleButton.Style>
                <Style TargetType="{x:Type ToggleButton}">
                    <Setter Property="Content" Value="Start"/>
                    <Style.Triggers>
                        <Trigger Property="IsChecked" Value="True">
                            <Setter Property="Content" Value="Stop"/>
                        </Trigger>
                    </Style.Triggers>
                </Style>
            </ToggleButton.Style>
        </ToggleButton>
```

Note: The `Style` Section of the `ToggleButton`is optional, it changes only the `Content` from Start to Stop (and vice versa).

Note2: Dont forget to insert your `VisualBrush` in the Border, otherwise the animation is not recognized.

Comment: I just have seen your Edit. In this Example they already use Buttons, therefore a `DataTrigger`is not necessary.

Comment: Updated my answer to fit your Edit

Comment: Thank Works great ! :) One additional question: if i stop the animation is the last picture from botom cutted and begins from top. How did i call them to complete the actual spin?

Comment: Unfortunately, i have never needed such an animation behaviour.  But i suggest you to take a look at `Storyboard.Seek` which moves the animation for- or backward a specified amount. + I' m always glad to help a thankful person.

Comment: Maybe the concept from this Question could solve your additional Question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9965262/stop-storyboard-at-exact-keyframe

Answer (score -1):

In general you can start/stop a storyboard using the start and stop method of the storyboard object.

In your example should be stb.Start() or stb.Stop()

Comment: well i alrdy tried this but the animation still does not stop